# How to autowire a spring DAO repository in its unit test?

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, junit

I am experimenting Spring's reactive support for DB operations. So I have created a repository as:

```
public interface FeatureRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Feature, UUID> {}
```

Now I want to test it through a unit test.

So my test is:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class FeatureRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    FeatureRepository featureRepository;
    .....

}
```

But I get error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of 
type 'x.y.z.FeatureRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which 
qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: 
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: @Repository add in the interface

Comment: Is that needed as I am extending ReactiveCrudRepository?

Answer (score 0):

Your DAO is managed as any other tested class, so without defining a specific ApplicationContext in your test runtime, Spring do nothing and the FeatureRepository bean is not known.

2 approaches :

- Your test is more about integration test, so your test runtime need to be [specify](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.2.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-detecting-config).
- Your test is more about unit test, I suggest you to mock your repository (pragrammatically or using framework like Mockito)

Regards.